# Different frequencies for sine wave generator in python

Tags: python

I am using the code below to generate a sine wave and it works fine. However, when I try to use large frequencies 500kHz and change the time period to 0.2us I expect to get a full sine wave with time period of 0.2us but what I get is just a straight line don't know why.

```
def sampled_sine_wave(freq):
    samples = 1000
    time_period = 2e-7
    time = linspace(0,time_period,samples)
    _ = plot(time,[sin(t*freq*2*np.pi) for t in time], linewidth=2)
    Vin1=([np.sin(t*freq*2*np.pi) for t in time])
    #print (Vin1)
return Vin1
```

Can somebody tell me why I am getting that and how can I solve it.
Thanks

Comment: The sine from 0 to 10% of a period [kinda looks like a straight line](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x%29+from+0+to+0.6). Is that what you're getting? Does it change if you change the period to 2e-6, ie one full period?

Comment: By "0.2us", do you mean 0.2 microseconds (0.000002 seconds)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, **you probably aren't actually getting a straight line**. If you [graph it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin%285e5%2Fpi*x%29+from+0+to+2e-7) in that range, it looks almost like a straight line. In fact, at the edge of that range, at `x=2e-7`, that sine function and `5e5*x` have [less than a 7% difference](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%285e5*2*pi*2e-7%29%2Fsin%285e5*2*pi*2e-7%29). You probably meant to use a full period, `time_period = 2e-6`, which [looks more like a sine wave](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+of+sin%285e5*2*pi*x%29+from+0+to+2e-6). You seem to know that the period of that function is 2 microseconds, but [2 microseconds is 2e-6 seconds, not 2e-7 seconds](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2+microseconds+to+seconds).

---

Wow, this took a while to write for such a short answer. I kept messing up and dividing by pi instead of multiplying and pasting the wrong links.